# Protractor Typescript - Type 'By' has no properties in common with type 'Locator'

Tags: typescript, protractor

[image]

These are the versions of everything

```
Error.
Protractor version : 5.2.0
npm : 3.10.10
node :6.9.5
typescript :2.6.0
```

Type 'By' has no properties in common with type 'Locator'

How do I fix this error?

Comment: In its current condition, this question is unlikely to be answerable.  Please see the guiance on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Specifically, we need a code example, and what you were expecting to happen.  Screenshots are unhelpful

Comment: By has only methods like binding,deepcss etc... it dont have css,xpath kind of properties.. while finding an element(by.css(''); is not working

Comment: I have a few comments: (1) I cannot reproduce this. (2) nameInput does not return a string. In fact, you are probably returning undefined. Your async task probably does not wait to be completed before you return value. (3) importing protractor/built/ptor has no value since the exported types are already included. (4)  If this is reproducible on other machines, or you feel like this is a problem, make a github repo so I can pull down the code and replicate it. If it is a problem, then we'll make sure to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there is a naming conflict in your test environment with `by`? You might try importing `by as by2` and then try `element(by2.css(...))` and if that resolves it you have a name conflict. I would NOT recommend continuing with that (by2) as a workaround though, you'd want to find the source of the naming conflict and resolve it.